# Execute function statement only after promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have the following code which fetches some data by implementing promises.

```
var TreeDataService = new DataService();

export default class TreeStore {
    treeData = [];

    getData() {
        TreeDataService.get().then(data => {
            this.treeData = data;
        },
            () => {
                alert("Error fetching data");
            });
        return this.treeData; //this returns empty array instead of returning the data fetched from TreeDataService.get
    }
}
```

How can I make `return this.treeData` execute only after the promise is fully resolved? I know I can put `return this.treeData` inside then's success method and return the entire `getData`method as a promise, but that will require again resolving the promise at the call site of `getData`.

EDIT: I understand that as it's a async operation, I cannot synchronously execute the return statement and can instead return a promise. But then how do I resolve that promise at call site? I am facing the same issue at calling code:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  treeData = TreeStoreObj.getData().then(data => {
    return data;
  }); // This will also execute asynchronously, so will be initially empty.

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-container">
        <TreeNode node={this.treeData} /> // So this will also be empty
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Earlier code will now be:

```
export default class TreeStore {
    treeData = [];

    return getData() {
        TreeDataService.get().then(data => {
            return this.treeData = data;
        },
            () => {
                alert("Error fetching data");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only return the promise. You cannot synchronously wait for something asynchronous.

Comment: @Bergi: I have added more code here. Can you figure out how can I pass the promise data to `treeData` synchronously?

Comment: a) think of what you want to show (render) when the promise is not yet fulfilled (or even rejected) b) initialise your state with that, and change it asynchronously from the promise callback

Comment: Btw, if your `TreeStore` does nothing else than what you have shown in your question, you should just omit it completely and call the `DataService` directly from your `App`

Comment: @Bergi: I am using Mobx (https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html) in my React app so I should not use setState. I have set `treeData` as `@observable` in TreeStore.js and my react components `App` and `TreeNode` as `@observer`. This should have worked but the app is still not rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something strange. `getData` should not return any value at all if you are using mobx. It should set store observable only. React component will automatically rerender when this observable value change.

Are you using mobx-react? If so show your integration code. If not try to use it ;)

Comment: Yeah I figured that out and have already incorporated that. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Async model does not allow you to execute `return this.treeData` after the promise is resolved. However, you might want to cache the promise not to invoke `TreeDataService.get()` several times.

For example (untested, just trying to show the main idea):

```
export default class TreeStore {
    treeData = [];
    treeDataPromise = null;

    getData() {
        if (this.treeDataPromise) return this.treeDataPromise;
        this.treeDataPromise = TreeDataService.get().then(data => {
            this.treeData = data;
            return this.treeData;
        },
            () => {
                alert("Error fetching data");
            });
        return this.treeDataPromise;
    }
}
```

Another option is to check if `this.treeData` is loaded, and return `Promise.resolve(this.treeData)` if this is the case.

Comment: `treeDataPromise` is a property, not a variable

Comment: right, should be addressed `this.treeDataPromise` in this case. thanks, edited :)